# Select where HSTORE value is $value Laravel

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, hstore

Using the query builder to try and select rows where a value in the HSTORE key $type is present.

My Where Statement:

```
->where("meta_data_fields->'$type'", 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I get this error:

```
Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "meta_data_fields->'Entity::hstore'" does      not exist
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what is meta_data_fields? a table name?

Comment: Column name that is type HSTORE

Comment: try this `->where("meta_data_fields", 'like', '%'.$query.'%')`

Comment: Here's the result

SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: operator does not exist: hstore ~~ unknown
LINE 1: ... aggregate from "meta_data" where "meta_data_fields" like $1
^
HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from "meta_data" where "meta_data_fields" like %dsadasd%)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's what worked in my situation with Laravel.

```
$result = \DB::select(\DB::raw("SELECT hstore_fields, id from table where lower(hstore_fields->'$type') like lower('%$query%')"));
```

Answer (score 0):

to get all records in table that have HSTORE

```
Model::where("meta_data_fields", 'like', '%'.$query.'%')->get();
```

This should do normally do the trick. In your case, data in meta_data_fields is a json string. if the search is performed on all rows in the table, will select all. So here is What I did, 
I created a queryScope in the model
1 - fetch all data
2 - extract meta_data_field and decode it
3 - loop through meta_data_field
4 - select only  that match the criteria and build the array

here is a table

```
+----+-------------+------------------------------------+-----------+
| id | name        | desc                               | vendor_id |
+----+-------------+------------------------------------+-----------+
|  1 | apples      | {"type":"fruit","origin":"mexico"} |         1 |
|  2 | oranges     | {"type":"fruit","origin":"peru"}   |         1 |
|  3 | Peaches     | {"type":"fruit","origin":"mexico"} |         2 |
|  4 | Cherries    | {"type":"fruit","origin":"us"}     |         1 |
|  5 | banans      | {"type":"fruit","origin":"brazil"} |      NULL |
|  6 | Water Melon | {"type":"fruit","origin":"mexico"} |         1 |
+----+-------------+------------------------------------+-----------+

public function scopeItems($name ="mexico"){
    $items = array();
    $data =  Self::get();
    $meta_fields = json_decode($data -> pluck('desc') ,true);
    foreach ($meta_fields as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($value['origin']) && $value['origin'] == $name ){
            $items[$key] = $data[$key] -> toArray();
        }
    }
    return $items;
}    
// output 
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => apples
        [desc] => Array
            (
                [type] => fruit
                [origin] => mexico
            )

        [vendor_id] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [name] => Peaches
        [desc] => Array
            (
                [type] => fruit
                [origin] => mexico
            )

        [vendor_id] => 2
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [id] => 6
        [name] => Water Melon
        [desc] => Array
            (
                [type] => fruit
                [origin] => mexico
            )

        [vendor_id] => 1
    )

)
```

Hope this works for you this time.

Comment: Kinda like this however I need to select from a specific key where $key is the meta_data_field->key

    where("meta_data_fields->$type", 'like', '%'.$query.'%')

Comment: meta_data table structure and data will help figure out the right if you can post them?

Comment: meta_data_id (UUID)
meta_data_company_id (UUID)
meta_data_fields(HSTORE)

Comment: if I understand this, inside meta_data_fields you have a string with different key values, is it  json string a serialized data?

Comment: @AndrewGoldenberg, I updated my answer, Hope this works for you this time.